# Generate Grid From Point does not create the cell size I ask for

Tags: arcgis

I want to create four equal size quadrants around a given point. I am using the Generate Grid From Point tool and getting the output below. This is great, except I'm trying to set a cell size of 80 by 80 meters and getting more like 60. I projected the point to NAD83 beforehand. Why is the size different from what I specify? Also if anyone knows how to avoid it being tilted that would be helpful as I'm still pretty new to ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Comment: No matter what size I put in, I get about three fourths of that width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in 'Environments' you select the correct output coordinate system. If you leave it as default it will not work correctly. Ran into this same issue myself and couldn't figure out why my grids were incorrect.